# Mysql select data for week based Positive or Negative total count

Tags: mysql, select

I want to get data for week based Positive or Negative highest total count. This is my table name `scraping_data` and `operators`

```
scraping_data:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| id         | operatorId   | subLabel  | createdDatetime       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2            | Negative  | 2023-06-02 18:16:21   |
| 2          | 3            | Negative  | 2023-06-12 23:16:21   |
| 3          | 2            | Positive  | 2023-06-30 15:16:21   |
| 4          | 3            | Positive  | 2023-06-22 14:16:21   |
| 5          | 2            | Negative  | 2023-06-22 14:16:21   |
| 6          | 2            | Negative  | 2023-06-03 14:16:21   |
| 7          | 2            | Positive  | 2023-06-03 14:16:21   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here in my table `id`  `1`,`6`,`7` from `week 1` and there `Negative` is highest count. So `week 1` count should show as `2`

Example output:

```
 -------------------------------------
| operatorId    | Week      | Count |
-------------------------------------
| OSE+          | Week 1    | -2    | (Negative count highst fon week 1)
| MBC           | Week 2    | -1    | (Negative count highst fon week 2)
| MBC           | Week 3    | -1    | (Negative count highst fon week 3)
-------------------------------------
```

I tried this query:

```
select 
    op.operatorName, 
    CONCAT('Week ', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WEEK(sd.createdDatetime))) as week,     SUM(CASE WHEN sd.subLabel = 'Negative' THEN concat('-', 1) ELSE 0 END) AS negative, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sd.subLabel = 'Positive' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS positive 
from scraping_data sd 
    inner join operators op on op.operatorId = sd.operatorId 
where sd.operatorId in (2,3) and sd.createdDatetime BETWEEN '2023-06-23 00:00:00' and '2023-06-23 23:59:59'  
GROUP by op.operatorName, sd.label, sd.subLabel,WEEK(sd.createdDatetime) 
ORDER BY WEEK(sd.createdDatetime), op.operatorName;
```

Output of current query:

[image]